# Create Azure AD Application using terraform(Invalid UUID)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using terraform to create an Azure AD application, I have tried the default example from the terraform samples https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/application also I have customized the code below from the one I created manually(basically, I have created an application manually in AD and got the details from the data resource using terraform for the created application). both the code throws same error

> Error: Value must be a valid UUID │ │   with
> azuread_application.example, │   on adapp.tf line 3, in resource
> "azuread_application" "example": │    3: resource
> "azuread_application" "example" {

This is the code I have customized from the original example

```
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  display_name     = "example"
  identifier_uris  = ["api://example-app"]
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADMultipleOrgs"

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"
    resource_access {
      id   = "..."
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  web {
    redirect_uris = ["https://app.example.net/account"]

    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

I have validated the "data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id", its not null and it producing the value.

Terraform Config:

> Terraform v0.15.4 on windows_amd64
>
> - provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azuread v1.6.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using the resource app id of `"Microsoft Graph"` (00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000) , so you have to provide what delegated permissions you need for your app to have in Microsoft graph like User.read etc.

**Some CLI commands that will help you to get the Microsoft Graph resource App Id's and Delegated Permissions Id's:**

```
 - az ad sp list --display-name "Microsoft Graph" --query
   '[].{appDisplayName:appDisplayName, appId:appId}' 
           --output table
 - az ad sp show --id 00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000 --query
   "oauth2Permissions[].{Value:value, Id:id}" --output table
```

[image]

So as you are already using the default Microsoft Graph App Id , we need to get the delegated permission ID's to provide in resource access id.

[image]

Then your terraform code will be as below :

```
data "azuread_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azuread_application" "example" {
  display_name     = "example"
  identifier_uris  = ["api://example-app"]
  owners           = [data.azuread_client_config.current.object_id]
  sign_in_audience = "AzureADMultipleOrgs"

  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"# resourceid of microsoft graph
    resource_access {
      id   = "e1fe6dd8-ba31-4d61-89e7-88639da4683d"  # User.Read
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }

  web {
    redirect_uris = ["https://app.example.net/account"]

    implicit_grant {
      access_token_issuance_enabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

**Doing a terraform plan :**

[image]

**Note :** Default Microsoft Graph App ID is `"00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"` and Default Windows Active Directory App ID (Azure AD Graph) is `"00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"`. Based on your requirement you can use Microsoft Graph or Azure AD Graph .